# Creating a btBvhTriangleMeshShape in libgdx from node of model

Tags: libgdx, bulletphysics

I want to add nodes of a model to btDynamicsWorld with btBvhTriangleMeshShape. I can do this with the whole model by passing model.meshpart, but nodes does not have meshparts.
I need this because only the required nodes need to be added to btDynamicsWorld.

Answer (score 0):

See the wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Bullet-Wrapper---Using-models

It's one line:

```
btCollisionShape shape = Bullet.obtainStaticNodeShape(model.nodes);
```

You can pass in as many nodes you like (or just one, if you prefer).

Comment: @Xoppa when using btCollisionShape shape = Bullet.obtainStaticNodeShape(model.nodes); the mesh shape look right in debug draw but rigid model object fall through it. I am using model exported via blender and converted using fbx-conv.. Please help.